# Display text in input of type number only on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is what I try to acomplish: I need an input field containing a value with a unit, that would look like this:

[image]

On focussing the input, I want it to move the unit to the right side, looking like this:

[image]

I can think of two ways to do so:
1. Replace input field with a Div that looks exactly like the input when focus is lost, and set the value of the input as its content:

```js
$('#fakeInput').bind('click', changeToRealInput);
  $('#realInput').bind('blur', changeToFakeInput);
  $('#realInput').trigger('blur');
  $('#unitAddon').html($('#realInput').attr('unit'));

  function changeToFakeInput() {
   // hide actual input and show a div with its contents instead
    $('#fakeInput').show();
    $('#realInputContainer').hide();
    $('#fakeInput').html($('#realInput').val() + $('#realInput').attr('unit'));
  }

  function changeToRealInput() {
   // hide fake-div and set the actual input active
    $('#fakeInput').hide();
    $('#realInputContainer').show();
    $('#realInput').focus();
  }
```

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

div#container {
    display: flex; 
    background: #8aaac7;   
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}

div#unitAddon,
input#realInput,
div#fakeInput {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
div#realInputContainer,
div#fakeInput {
    border: 2px solid #dadada;
}
div#realInputContainer {
    display: flex; 
}
div#unitAddon {
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="fakeInput"></div>
  <div id="realInputContainer">
      <input type="number" unit="kg" id="realInput" value="3.3">
      <div id="unitAddon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(also see [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8x9r8nw/5/))

Problem here is (as you can see in the screenshot above) that, depending on your local settings, chrome automatically converts the decimal point into a comma (in the input, but not in the fake-div)

Another way I thought of is: When the focus is lost, set the size of the input field to match its content and, by doing so, pull the addon displaying the unit just behind the number.
Problem here is to get the size of the content of an input (cross-browser):

```js
$('#realInput').bind('focus', changeToRealInput);
  $('#realInput').bind('blur', changeToFakeInput);
  $('#realInput').trigger('blur');
  $('#unitAddon').html($('#realInput').attr('unit'));

  function changeToFakeInput() {
    // here is the question: what width should it be?
    $('#realInput').css({'width' : '40%'});
  }

  function changeToRealInput() {
    $('#unitAddon').css({'width' : 'auto'});
    $('#realInput').css({'width' : '100%'});
  }
```

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

div#container {
    display: flex; 
    background: #8aaac7;   
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
}

div#unitAddon,
input#realInput{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

div#realInputContainer {
    border: 2px solid #dadada;
    display: flex; 
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

div#realInputContainer.setAddonAway > div#unitAddon {
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="realInputContainer" class="setAddonClose">
      <input type="number" unit="kg" id="realInput" value="3.3">
      <div id="unitAddon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[also see this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etcancy7/3/)

I could accomlish this with an input[type=text], but I dont want to loose the benefits of type[number] (min/max/step validation, on-screen keyboard, etc.)

Is there any way of getting around the flaws of my two ideas? Or is thre a more elegant way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to: (1) make the input box to cover the entire container; (2) create a helper element, and set it the same length as the input value via JS, and make it invisible as a place holder; (3) apply some style for moving around the unit box.

**[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZodYNg)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".value").text($(".number").val());
  $(".unit").text($(".number").attr("unit"));

  $(".number").on("change keypress input", function() {
    $(".value").text($(".number").val());
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  border: 4px solid teal;
  width: 200px;
}

.container > * {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.number {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.value {
  visibility: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.unit {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: white;
}

.number:focus ~ .value {
  flex: 1;
}

.number:focus ~ .unit {
  flex: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <input class="number" type="number" value="1.23" unit="kg">
  <span class="value"></span>
  <span class="unit"></span>
</div>
```